# Create React App запускаю команду npx create-react-app my-app, получаю ошибки

Tags: reactjs, npm

Хотел установить реакт и создать приложение для этого воспользовался командой с официального сайта

`npx create-react-app my-app`

получил ошибки

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...erify":"0.0.0","tty
-b'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\comp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-26T08_32_19_2
60Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts
 cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-app/ from D:\Программирование\JavaScript\5.1.React\app
Done.
```

Как решить данную проблему? заранее благодарен

Comment: говорят, такое может происходить из-за медленного интернета. стандартные рекомендации: почистить кеш npm с force и попробовать снова

Comment: Спасибо помогло!